# Common usage pattern for implementing SCD2?

Tags: sql, data-warehouse

We have written some custom Python code (running on Composer) that attempts to sync data from our on-prem database into Google BigQuery. The first step looks in the source table for "change_date greater-than-or-equal-to what BQ already has" and grabs those updated rows and appends them into a staging table along with a "data capture timestamp" field. Let's assume the source data has a unique primary key. The staging table, after a few runs, will have many rows for each primary key data point: at least one every time we've observed a change, and maybe a few dupe rows (given the "greater-than-or-equal-to" capture logic).

My question is: is there a common pattern used to translate such an append-only staging table into a final SCD2 table with valid_from, valid_to, etc.? Requirements:

1. This pattern should either recreate the entire final table (from the staging table) if it doesn't exist, OR,
2. if there is data there already, should implement SCD2 for the changed rows (change valid_to to change_date for existing record, add a new record with valid_to = null).
3. It should also handle the case where maybe there have been many first-step appends into the staging table in between subsequent writes to the final table. (i.e. one row could have multiple changes to it logged in the staging table).

I'm aware of this pattern: https://medium.com/happiestneurons/slowly-changing-dimension-type-2-scd2-in-big-query-95330ce31625

It's awesome, however, it fails on requirements 1 and 3.

I am battling my way through this, and think I figure it out. But this has to be a pretty common data-warehousing pattern, and so thought I'd ask if there's an easy reference or commonly-understood way to do this.

Comment: Although type-2 data structures can be useful, you might just want to store a snapshot each day and use the built-in partitioning.

Comment: Thanks for your response, Gordon. Good idea for most cases. However snapshots make me nervous for a few reasons: 1) potential for failure just means we miss a whole day, bad for analysts who want to use the data later; 2) even though storage is cheap, very large and slowly changing dimensions will take up more space than needed.